# NameError in Django template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am developing a simple Django project. However, I am not very familiar with python as well as Django. It keeps throwing "NameError".

In my template, the code looks like this:

```
{% for habbit_source in habbit_source_list %}
<span class="habbit-hide">{{habbit_source.get_tomato_achieve}}</span>
...
{% endfor %}
```

`get_tomato_achieve` is a function of the Model class: `task.models.HabbitSource`, which is defined like this:

```
def get_tomato_achieve(self):
    return rules.get_achieve_tomato(self)
```

In `rules.py`, I want to judge the type of input parameter at the beginning of `get_tomato_achieve(habbit)`, however whether I use

```
if type(habbit) == task.models.HabbitSource:
```

or

```
if isinstance(habbit, task.models.HabbitSource):
```

It will throw `NameError: Name task is not defined.` (Of course it's defined. it's my app's name.)

And if I write `from task.models import HabbitSource`, it will throw `ImportError: cannot import HabbitSource`.

I really don't know how to solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because `task` is the name of your application, that's no reason to think it would be defined in any particular module. Python's name scoping rules are very very simple: nothing is defined unless it is imported or assigned in that module. If you don't have anything that defines the name `task`, it remains undefined.

As for why you can't do `from task.models import HabbitSource`, you might have a circular dependency. If `rules` imports `models` and `models` imports `rules`, the dependency cannot be resolved at import time, so you get that error.

One possibility would be to cheat and use the internal model name attribute, which is a string:

```
if habbit._meta.object_name == 'HabbitSource':
```

Alternatively, you could rethink your architecture: type checking is not usually idiomatic Python, normally you would simply define your class's methods appropriately and just call them.